# Pattern recognition learning by examples

Tags: machine-learning, references, pattern-recognition

I am learning pattern recognition. But in the book I am reading there is almost exclusively a theory with few examples.  Is there a special book / web site etc, with a lot of tasks covering all main topics of pattern recognition? I understand the theory, but I need practice so I'd like to find a book with list of problems like books on mathematical analysis and so on.